# Performance impact due to time required for shuffling in Quicksort

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, quicksort

As a programmer with non CS background, I am learning algorithms.

When explaining the performance of quicksort in an [Algorithm book](http://www.amazon.de/Algorithms-Robert-Sedgewick/dp/032157351X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1394794069&sr=8-1&keywords=algorithm) and also elsewhere on the web, I do not see any reference to the time/space needed for shuffling. I *do* understand that shuffling is important to have the $O(n\log n)$ performance, but shuffling itself would have a complexity of $O(n)$. Why does this become irrelevant in the total performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little more detail than [Dave Clarke's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23388/9550).

Remember that $O(n\log n)$ means that there are constants $c_1$ and $n_1$ such that, for all $n\geq n_1$, the running time of the sorting phase is at most $c_1n\log n$ steps.<sup>1</sup>  Similarly, the running time of the shuffling phase is at most $c_2n$ steps, for all $n\geq n_2$.  That means that, as long as $n>n_1$ and $n>n_2$, the total running time is at most $c_1n\log n + c_2n$.  As long as $n\ge2$, $\log n\ge1$ (I'm assuming logs to base 2; if you want to take logs to some other base $b$, you need $n\ge b$), we have
\begin{equation*}
    c_1n\log n + c_2n \le c_1n\log n + c_2n\log n = (c_1+c_2)n\log n\,,
\end{equation*}
as long as $n\ge \max\,\{n_1, n_2, 2\}$.

We conclude that the total running time is $O(n\log n)$.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, this is something like the expected running time: as is well known, the worst-case running time is actually $O(n^2)$.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that the $O(n\log n)$ component dominates the $O(n)$ component, hence the $O(n)$ part can be ignored in the statement of complexity.

Comment: Also, the effect of actually shuffling is usually achieved by picking a uniformly random pivot.